# is there any way to increase heap_size in weka 3.7.13 for executing the big data like 10 millions instances?

Tags: java, weka, heap-size

I am facing following issues in the **weka 3.7.13** ;Latest version were not working on my system.

1. inital **heap =128MB ; Current (used)= 808MB;  max available = 913MB;**
2. i set **maxheap=2000M in runweka.ini , javaOpts=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx1024m**
3. package manager on tool are not working even no classifier are shown there.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to basics:

- instead of downloading an installer, download the Weka release as zip file, e.g.g, [stable version/other platforms](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/downloading_weka/#other-platforms) (this can be used on **all** platforms, it just doesn't integrate itself into your Desktop; also doesn't require any admin rights)
- unzip the downloaded archive
- open a terminal (*command prompt* if you are on Windows), navigate to the directory where you unzipped the archive to and then into the directory that contains the `weka.jar` file
- start Weka from the terminal using this command:

  ```
  java -Xmx2000m -jar weka.jar
  ```

You can then confirm the maximum memory in the GUIChooser:

- Help -> System info
- check value for `memory.max`

Comment: i faced this issue:::java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at weka.gui.SplashWindow.invokeMain(SplashWindow.java:306)
 at weka.gui.GUIChooser.main(GUIChooser.java:92)

Comment: What version of Java are you using (`java -version`)?

Comment: i am using java8

Comment: Try with Java 11. Weka installers come with Java 17 nowadays.